# Mongoid update attributes : how not to insert when field names don't already exist in the collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I'm trying to do update_attributes with Mongoid in a Rails 3 application

The problem I'm running into is this:

Let's say my collection has the following fields:

{"Name" : "foo", "email" : "bar" }

**Here's the scenario**

if I do this:

```
@person = Person.where(:Name => "foo", :_id = "some_id")
```

and then I do this:

```
@person.update_attributes(:Name => "baba-fooka", :Last_Name => "baba-bara")
```

The line of code above updates the record in mongodb, but also **adds a new field** to the document.

How can I use the update_attributes method with a validation which doesn't allow inserting fields which don't already exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like what you want is [allow_dynamic_fields](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/documents.html#dynamic_fields) set to false in the mongoid config file.  Dynamic fields is on by default which allows attributes to get set and persisted on the document even if a field was not defined for them.

Go into `config/mongoid.yml` under options set `allow_dynamic_fields: false`.  It should already be there but commented out and set to true.  Make sure it says false.

Comment: thanks. this is exactly what I was trying to do. and allow_dynamic_fields: false worked. It seems by default its set to true.